# Including PHRETS into a Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, include, autoload, rets, phrets

How can I include this library: `https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS` into a symfony project?

This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "marysalcedo/reactive-pandora",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/",
            "SymfonyStandard": "app/"
        },
        "files": []
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "maciejczyzewski/bottomline": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "troydavisson/phrets": "2.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use the object \PHRETS\Configuration I get an error:

```
new \PHRETS\Configuration();
```

This is the error I get back:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]                   
  Attempted to load class "Configuration" from namespace "PHRETS".             
  Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g.
```

Why isn't it being included?

Comment: try without the first slash as follow `new PHRETS\Configuration();`

Comment: Did you followed this advice *Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g.*?

Answer (score 1):

Are you **absolutely** sure you actually installed the package?

1) I used custom composer-based project and tried to create new instance of that class and it worked. Output bellow.

2) Then I installed fresh copy of `Symfony2` (`v2.6`) and the package. Tried creating instance and it worked as well.

Try this:

```
php composer.phar update
```

And then in your controller:

```
$c = new \PHRETS\Configuration();
var_dump($c);
```

Output in my setup:

```
object(PHRETS\Configuration)[570]
  protected 'username' => null
  protected 'password' => null
  protected 'login_url' => null
  protected 'user_agent' => string 'PHRETS/2.0' (length=10)
  protected 'user_agent_password' => null
  protected 'rets_version' => 
    object(PHRETS\Versions\RETSVersion)[571]
      protected 'number' => string '1.5' (length=3)
      protected 'valid_versions' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '1.5' (length=3)
          1 => string '1.7' (length=3)
          2 => string '1.7.1' (length=5)
          3 => string '1.7.2' (length=5)
          4 => string '1.8' (length=3)
  protected 'http_authentication' => string 'digest' (length=6)
  protected 'strategy' => null
  protected 'options' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

### Side note

Just to clear the a confusion about `use` statements.

- Putting `use` is not necessary when you specify class's `FQN`.
- If you leave out the leading backslash PHP will try to find a an alias in you `use` statements that matches namespace. If none found, it will assume current class's namespace. Take well known `Doctrine` mapping example:

  ```
  use `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` as ORM
  ....
  @ORM\Column() // This resolves to `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column` `FQN`
  ```
- If you would use class name only (e.g. `Configuration`) `use` statement would be mandatory.